# How to map the json by key for such API response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

This is how an API reponse looks like.

```
{
"keys": ["CustomerId", "Name", "Gender"],
"value": [["1", "Ram", "Male"]]
}
```

Angular VM

```
function Customer(){
 return this.Customer = {
      "CustId": "",
      "Name": "",
      "Gender": "",
 }
}
```

Angular AJAX Call.

```
$http.get(url)
        .then(function(data)){
          var cust = new Customer();
          //for now I am doing this way.
           cust.Id = data.value[0][0];
           cust.Name = data.value[0][1];
           cust.Gender = data.value[0][1];

        }
```

I don't want to map the properties by index.

**These APIs not into my control** 
Is there any way, where I can map the properties by key (in response) as below.

```
           cust.Id = data.value[0]["CustomerId"];
           cust.Name = data.value[0]["Name"];
           cust.Gender = data.value[0]["Gender"];
```

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you modify your API response to be better formatted JSON? That's not a quality structured response.

Comment: @Brant, Wish I could. But that's not into my control

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see of achieving something like this is by finding the index of each key and using that as the index when accessing your values like this:

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(data){
        var cust = new Customer();

        cust.Id = data.value[0][data.keys.indexOf('CustomerId')];
        cust.Name = data.value[0][data.keys.indexOf('Name')];
        cust.Gender = data.value[0][data.keys.indexOf('Gender')];
    });
```

But note, this will only work if the keys and values match up ... which I assume they will.

Comment: Thanks!! really useful upvoted for now,will accept it(lets see if someone has other way)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use ES6, the best workaround (for this poorly made API) would be to create a parser function like that:

```
function parseResponse(response) {
    const {keys, value: objects} = response;

    return objects.map(object => {
        const parsedValue = {};

        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
            parsedValue[key] = object[index];
        });

        return parsedValue;
    });
}
```

Tests:

```
const response = {
    "keys": ["CustomerId", "Name", "Gender"],
    "value": [["1", "Ram", "Male"]]
};

parseResponse(response); // Outputs [{CustomerId: "1", Name: "Ram", Gender: "Male"}]
```

If you wish, I could make that with ES5. Just say the word :)

---

**EDIT**

ES5 Version:

```
function parseResponse(response) {
    var keys = response.keys;
    var objects = response.value;
    var response = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var formattedValue = {};

        for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            var key = keys[j];
            formattedValue[key] = objects[i][j];
        }

        response.push(formattedValue);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, Yes sure please make with ES 5 as well & keep this as well in the post.

Comment: Yes, of course. Edited my answer :) Please, don't forget to upvote!